# How to deal with removal of a permission for a broadcast receiver in Android M?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've got some legacy code which I am making permission safe for Marshmallow.

There is a broadcast using the PHONE_STATE permission as follows:

```
<receiver android:name="redacted.TheBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If the PHONE_STATE permission is granted but then later the user denied then when there is a phone call there is a permissions related crash. 
But the crash occurs *before* the Broadcast Receiver's onReceive() is called (the crash is in android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver). That means that the broadcast receiver does not get the chance to even check if the permission is granted or not and deal with that situation.

So my question is, if there is a broadcast receiver such as this how can the code deal with the situation where the user has disabled the permission because AFAIK there is no API to monitor for changes in permissions as they occur, therefore the code cannot know on the fly that the permission has been revoked, and therefore it can't deregister its broadcast receiver.

Comment: Does a crash dialog appear in this case? Or is this a "silent" stack trace, just showing up in LogCat but not harming the user experience directly? If the latter, probably the answer is just to live with those messages, and to check in something like `onCreate()` of an `Application` to see if you hold the permission and toggle the enabled status of the receiver to match. But if the user sees a typical crash dialog... that's bad.

Comment: There's an "Unfortunately, XXX has stopped" dialog.

Comment: Oooo... that's an edge case that I'm betting they didn't think of. At least as a stopgap, you might need to use `AlarmManager` or something to check to make sure the permission and receiver status are synchronized periodically. That won't help for calls between the revoked permission and the next `AlarmManager` check, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Also, can you publish the stack trace that you get from this? It might help us come up with other ideas.

Comment: Since `Application.onCreate()` will be invoked before creating your `BroadcastReceiver`, is it possible you could check there to see if you have the `PHONE_STATE` permission granted, and enable or disable the component there? (see http://www.grokkingandroid.com/enabling-and-disabling-broadcastreceivers/)

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce this. If I revoke permission, I just don't receive the broadcast. Stack trace would be interesting. :)

Comment: @kcoppock - what if the permission is granted, and then the broadcast receiver is created/enabled, then when the app is still running the user revokes the permission?

Comment: @Woofbeans: If the user revokes a permission for your app through Settings, your process is terminated.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this today. The difference is yesterday I was running in debug mode interactively using android studio, I think android studio/adb was keeping the app alive after the permission was revoked, so when a call came in there was a crash. However when running the app independently of AS it gets terminated when the permission is revoked and the next call is not forwarded to the broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the permission in Android Marsmallow you may want to check for permission before your receiver is called like this:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.PHONE_STATE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.PHONE_STATE)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.PHONE_STATE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PHONE_STATE);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

It is a late answer but i hope it helps someone!!!

Answer (score 1):

The final version of Android M is not out yet (the final api is out, but not the platform code), so hopefully the platform will handle permission checking before calling your receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to reproduce the issue on 6.0.1 with no success. I'm attaching a link for the [test project](https://github.com/furmana/PhoneStateTest) I used.
The scenario is simple:

1. Run with the permission ON. Everything works as expected. The `onReceive` is called.
2. Turn OFF the permission. The expected result of the app crashing when phone state changed, does not occur.

Unless anyone has a different result I think this issue is "solved" in a way.