# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL on android 7 (N OS)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-7.0-nougat

I want to make outgoing call using adb connection on Nexus 5x(N OS) device.

I am sending out a broadcast intent and observed error:

> Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL (has extras) }
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL from pid=5569, uid=2000
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
>           at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3507)
>           at com.android.commands.am.Am.sendBroadcast(Am.java:772)
>           at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:404)
>           at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
>           at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855003/how-to-deal-with-removal-of-a-permission-for-a-broadcast-receiver-in-android-m

Comment: did you add runtime permission??

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL):

> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

Hence, you cannot use it for your own broadcast `Intent`.

Comment: So there is no way to test it more than actually doing an `adb reboot`?

Comment: @JCarlosR: I do not know what the `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` `Intent` has to do with `adb reboot`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad (wrong page). I meant that `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` gives the same error for AndroidTV. Since it is also protected by the system I didn't find a way to start this intent and had to actually reboot.

Answer (score 4):

Working fine with this command:

```
adb shell su 0 am broadcast -a android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL -e android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER 'xxxxxxxxx'
```